# What are the rules for a C++ object returned from a Q_INVOKABLE to be owned and collected by QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ class that is exposed in QML as a singleton that produces other types

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<DomainManager>("my.pkg", 1, 0, "DomainManager", domain_provider);
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Control>("my.pkg", 1, 0, "Control", "Get it fresh from DomainManager");
```

The `DomainManager` has a function

```
Q_INVOKABLE Control* controlWriter(QString partition);
```

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership an object returned from a `Q_INVOKABLE` is owned by QML and should be deleted by the GC. The only exception seems to be when a parent is set on the returned object, which is not the case.

I have a `StackView` which contains panels with a property:

```
property Control ctrl: DomainManager.controlWriter(dummy.name)
```

I have verified that when I pop the panel off the stack, `Component.onDestruction` gets called, so the panel does get deleted.

However, I put the following destructor on the C++ object, and it does not get deleted until the whole application exits.

```
~Control() { qDebug() << "deleting control"; };
```

The only way I've found to get rid of the `Control` object is to call `ctrl.destroy()` in `Component.onDestruction` to manually free it.

Why does QML not free this object?

The full QML file holding the property is as follows. `ctrl` is not used outside this file.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import my.pkg 1.0

Image {
  id: dummy
  property string name
  property Control ctrl: DomainManager.controlWriter(dummy.name)

  source: "dummy.jpg"
  fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

  Connections {
    target: gamepad
    onAxisLeftYChanged: {
      ctrl.id = dummy.name
      ctrl.x = gamepad.axisLeftY * 32767
      ctrl.yaw = gamepad.axisLeftX * 32767
      ctrl.publish()
    }
    onAxisLeftXChanged: {
      ctrl.id = dummy.name
      ctrl.x = gamepad.axisLeftY * 32767
      ctrl.yaw = gamepad.axisLeftX * 32767
      ctrl.publish()
    }
  }
  Component.onDestruction: {
    // not sure why this requires manual clean-up
    ctrl.destroy()
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case QML does delete the Control object, in the following link you can find my test project https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51729672

Comment: _When the object is returned to QML as the return value of a method call, QML will track it and delete it if there are no remaining JavaScript references to it and it has no QObject::parent()._  But looks like Qt won't release object until QML engine deleted.

Comment: @eyllanesc I submitted a PR to your code to demonstrate that when you set the property to null, it does not clean up the object.

Comment: @Pepijn that problem is caused because you are losing the position of the pointer, QML will try to clean the pointer stored in ctrl, and in your case you have set it to null. Consequently, it is now your responsibility to do so.

Comment: @Pepijn it's like doing: `Control * ctrl = new Control;
ctrl = nullptr;
delete ctrl;` The pointer was lost because delete deletes the reference stored in ctrl. 
delete removes the variable that the pointer refers to.

Comment: @eyllanesc I was just trying to emulate the same behavior I see when I delete the parent without creating a whole stack view. Normally in JS, setting a variable to null frees the object.

Comment: @Pepijn 
Well, it seems that it is not what the documentation points out, seeing it from the point of view of C++ it will only eliminate the reference stored by the pointer when the program is closed.

Comment: Isn't this the very essence of garbage collection? I delete the reference, the GC cleans up the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find out what's QML GC:

**main.cpp**

```
DomainManager *example = nullptr;

static QObject *domain_provider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
    return example;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    example = new DomainManager;

    qmlRegisterSingletonType<DomainManager>("my.pkg", 1, 0, "DomainManager", domain_provider);
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Control>("my.pkg", 1, 0, "Control", "Get it fresh from DomainManager");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(example, &DomainManager::collectGarbage,
                     [&engine]() {
        engine.collectGarbage();
        qDebug("collectGarbage");
    });
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**QML**

```
Window
{
    visible: true
    height: 640
    width: 480

    Component {
        id: test
        Item {
            property Control ctrl: DomainManager.controlWriter("test")
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var c = test.createObject()
        console.log("Control created")
        c.destroy()
        //DomainManager.collectGarbage()
        console.log("Window onCompleted")
    }
}
```

In the above code, I add an additional signal `collectGarbage` of `DomainManager` to demonstrate GC.

> The object is owned by JavaScript. When the object is returned to QML
>   as the return value of a method call, QML will track it and delete it
>   if there are no remaining JavaScript references to it and it has no
>   QObject::parent().

1. The output of the above:

> ```
> qml: Control created 
> qml: Window onCompleted
> ```

2. Then uncomment `DomainManager.collectGarbage()` tells QML engine to `collectGarbage`.
   The output will be:

> ```
> qml: Control created
> collectGarbage
> qml: Window onCompleted
> deleting control
> ```

3. Change ownership of `control` object to Cpp `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(control, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);` The output:

> ```
> qml: Control created
> collectGarbage
> qml: Window onCompleted
> ```

**Conclusion:**

The code demo shows what if I force release the garbage. 
GC is **not** the smart pointer. When the object's reference count becomes zero, QML GC will destroy the object which returns from `Q_INVOKABLE` function except `CppOwnership`. But not immediately. Which I consider it similar to Java GC.

collectGarbage:

> Normally you don't need to call this function; the garbage collector
>   will automatically be invoked when the QJSEngine decides that it's
>   wise to do so (i.e. when a certain number of new objects have been
>   created). However, you can call this function to explicitly request
>   that garbage collection should be performed as soon as possible.